# Impossible to install Gitlab on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: git, ubuntu-12.04, gitlab, deb

i've downloaded the gitlab deb file and rpm(alien conversion).
In all two cases dpkg finish installation sucessfully.

But when i try to start

```
gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

the process stop(pause) on this line :

```
* ruby_block[supervise_redis_sleep] action run
```

I only could stop it with ctrl+c shourtcut and after i could read this error

```
================================================================================
Error executing action `run` on resource 'ruby_block[supervise_redis_sleep]'
================================================================================
```

if i try to start by default

```
gitlab-ctl start or gitlab-ctl restart
```

i've this message:

```
warning: redis: unable to open supervise/ok: file does not exist
```

Could i resolve it to work?

***PS the deb file downloaded is gitlab_6.6.4-omnibus-1.ubuntu.12.04_amd64.deb***

Comment: facing same issue.. any luck solving it?(using centOS)

Comment: I have the same issue in Debian 7.

Answer (score 8):

This is (now) a [known problem](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/160). For a [workaround](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/README.md), use this:

```
sudo cp /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/runit/files/default/gitlab-runsvdir.conf /etc/init/
sudo initctl start gitlab-runsvdir
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

Comment: Replace `sudo initctl start gitlab-runsvdir` with `sudo service gitlab-runsvdir start` if you use `systemd` instead of `upstart`

Comment: Thank you! This solved my issues on a Debian machine after an upgrade of gitlab. I had to use the command suggested by martin-g (initctl command was not found)

Answer (score 1):

For CentOS:

error:
**warning: redis: unable to open supervise/ok: file does not exist**

```
  # gitlab-ctl status
  run: gitaly: (pid 11526) 907s; run: log: (pid 11581) 906s
  run: postgresql: (pid 11810) 881s; run: log: (pid 11834) 880s
  warning: puma: unable to open supervise/ok: file does not exist
  run: redis: (pid 11484) 913s; run: log: (pid 11483) 913s
```

```
  # cd /opt/gitlab/sv/puma/supervise
  # mkfifo control
  # mkfifo ok
  # pkill runsv
```

```
# /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/runsvdir-start &
# gitlab-ctl reconfigure
…………..
Running handlers:
Running handlers complete
Chef Client finished, 5/794 resources updated in 21 seconds
GitLab Reconfigured!
```

Ref:

- https://forum.gitlab.com/t/gitlab-ce-13-0-4-ce-0-failed-stuck-on-puma/38389

Answer (score 0):

Do you have redis-server installed and running? GitLab requires it to work. I would also recommend, that you follow the official installation instructions over at their repository:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/6-6-stable/doc/install/installation.md

Comment: Why redis-server will be not installed automatically by dependencies as all deb files does?
It's a wrong packaging?
Normally in a debian package, all dependencies will be resolved by apt/deb "Depends:" tag on control file...

Comment: If the deb was linked, we could have a look at that. That it is installed also does not automatically mean that the service is running. It's possible that the update.rc freeze is active, etc

Answer (score 0):

I Tried all the answers above, none of them helped.

Incase you want to save your time and your server can be rebooted
Just reboot the server it will kill all the runsv processes:

```
sudo reboot
```